# Mis contribuciones en git hub no aumentan al hacer push

Tags: git, github, git-push

Llevo trabajando en un proyecto desde hace dos meses, cuando hago push, me actualiza los archivos, registra el commit pero no lo

Comment: ¿estás haciendo eso en repositorio público o privado?

Comment: A lo mejor no estás completando el

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo en un repositorio publico. El procedimiento que sigo,es add. commit y push. He hecho de todo, pero aun así no me registra en mí perfil las contribuciones hechas, faltó aclarar que el repositorio fue creado por mí

Comment: verifica la [dirección de correo electrónico asociada al commit](https://help.github.com/es/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)

Comment: Has hecho ``` git push origin nombreRama```, prueba a ver.

Comment: @JeanCarlosOrtiz podrías editar la pregunta y completarla? Parece que te falta una frase al final.

Comment: Creo que marca las contribuciones solamente al pushar o mergear a master, o hace un tiempo era así

Comment: Los push que hago son a master, realizo el push origin master, mi correo está verificado y adicional a eso, soy el dueño del repositorio.